# Importing Package in Python - variable undefined

Tags: import, package, global-variables

I’m trying to get my head around global variables. I’ve created a package called Test_Folder containing two files - `__init__.py` and `test_module.py`. I then have a separate file called `Test_File.py` (outside of the package) where I’m trying to run the code from.

In my test_module I’ve defined a function:

```
def practice():
    print("Hello", constant_one)
 
practice()
```

In my `__init__ file` I then set constant_one and define the scope of `__all__`:

```
__all__ = ["test_module"]
 
constant_one = 23
```

Finally – in my test_file I import the package:

```
from Test_Folder import *
```

However – when I run this import I get a NameError – constant_one is not defined.

I understand this means that the practice function is being run however I’m not sure why constant_one isn’t defined?

Answer (score 0):

Importing `const_one` in `test_module.py` will solve this issue,

```
from Test_Folder import constant_one
```

Comment: Thank you - that does indeed work. Unfortunately in the code I'm working on I have a number of variables and modules. Does this mean I would need to import each variable separately in each module?

Comment: you can import everything at one shot, but it has to be imported before using.
`from Test_Folder import *`